# Can start custom systemd service, can't enable it

Tags: centos, systemd

I want to create a daemon of Telegram-cli (https://github.com/vysheng/tg). I have created the file `/etc/systemd/system/telegram.service` with the following contents:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
KillMode=process
ExecStart=/usr/bin/telegram-daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

And a file `/usr/bin/telegram-daemon` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /var/run/telegram.sock
cd /root/tg
bin/telegram-cli  -k tg-server.pub -W -s action.lua  -S /var/run/telegram.sock > /dev/null 2>&1 &
exit
```

I can perfectly start this service using `systemctl start telegram`, I can enable it using `systemctl enable telegram`:

```
 ln -s '/etc/systemd/system/telegram.service' '/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/telegram.service'
```

When I manually start the server and check if telegram is running using `ps aux | grep telegram` it is running:

```
root      2506  0.0  2.2 359208 22632 ?        S    apr24   1:11 bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -W -s action.lua -S /var/run/telegram.sock
root      8177  0.0  0.0 112660   964 pts/0    R+   12:11   0:00 grep --color=auto telegram
```

However when I reboot, the cli isn't started. The status of the service (`systemctl status -l telegram`) is:

```
telegram.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/telegram.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since zo 2015-04-26 12:13:14 UTC; 48s ago
  Process: 393 ExecStart=/usr/bin/telegram-daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 393 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/telegram.service

apr 26 12:13:14 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Starting telegram.service...
apr 26 12:13:14 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started telegram.service.
```

How can I solve this? Note that I also tried to change the `type` to `forking`. And I tried to directly run the telegram command from the service. In the latest situatuon `systemctl start telegram` keeps running for ever.

Thanks in advance!

P.s. I'm running Centos 7

EDIT: note that starting the service at @reboot via crontab has the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this. Here is the `/etc/systemd/system/telegram.service` file. Note that this is the only file you'll need.

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/run/telegram.sock
ExecStart=/root/tg/bin/telegram-cli  -k /root/tg/tg-server.pub -W -s /root/tg/action.lua  -S /var/run/telegram.sock > /var/log/telegram.log &
KillMode=process

ExecStop=/bin/rm -rf /var/run/telegram.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You'll have to install and compile telegram under /root/tg. 
Now you can start it with `systemctl start telegram`, stop it with `systemctl stop telegram` and enable it (so it will run at boot) via `systemctl enable telegram`

Now you can start sending messages via `echo "msg $username $msg" | socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/telegram.sock`. Replace $username and $msg with your values. This can be simplified by creating a bash script (place it under /usr/bin/telegram-msg and do a `chmod  +x /usr/bin/telegram-msg`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "msg $1 $2" | socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/telegram.sock
```

Now you can send telegram messages via `telegram-msg $username $msg`.