# Systemd service not running after VM reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

Here is my `systemd` service status

```
root@ip-10-111-11-4:/home/foolala# sudo systemctl status mycustom-service.service
● mycustom-service.service - Custom service to manage docker-comopose for foolala via web
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mycustom-service.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-04-23 09:49:05 UTC;
   Main PID: 2233163 (mycustom-service)
      Tasks: 20 (limit: 75911)
     Memory: 6.9G
     CGroup: /system.slice/mycustom-service.service
             └─2243666 /usr/local/bin/mycustom-service

Jul 23 09:49:05 ip-10-111-11-4 systemd[1]: Started Custom service to manage docker-comopose for foolala via web.
```

It is running on `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`

Despite the service being `enabled`, after a VM reboot I don't see the service running and I have to manually start it myself. Any ideas why?

**update**: just wanted to clarify that this is the state after a manual `systemctl start mycustom-service.service`. Is there a way to check that it is indeed enabled and will start after a VM reboot?

Comment: so that status is from *after* you started it manually, right? What do the logs say (`journalctl -u ...`)? Not sharing the actual unit file doesn't help us much…

Comment: `Active: active (running)` looks like its running based on what you've just posted

Comment: you are both correct, I updated my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why won't my enabled systemd service start on boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322720/why-wont-my-enabled-systemd-service-start-on-boot), Also: [Can start custom systemd service, can't enable it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198700/can-start-custom-systemd-service-cant-enable-it), [How to make systemd service start at boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645331/how-to-make-systemd-service-start-at-boot)

Comment: Also: [Check if service is Enabled, Disabled, Running or Stopped](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599558/check-if-service-is-enabled-disabled-running-or-stopped)